# How to get $HOME in MinGW to not be /c

Tags: windows-xp, mingw, msys

Any chance that being logged in as Administrator would change how mingw installs? I am running XP.  My home directory turns out to be `/c`, not something in /home`.

Details: Having failed once, I removed MinGW package *(mingw-get-inst-20120426)* then reinstalled it.  During the install of MinGW I chose every option and elected to download latest packages.

I checked my `Start->Programs->Mingw->MinGW Shell` properties. it is starting `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat` and the start-in directory is `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin`.  I have determined that `/` is `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0`.

But when I run the bat, at the mingw prompt `echo $HOME` says `/c`.  And there is no directory named `/home`.  `echo $USERNAME` = Administrator.

Can someone tell me what I did to end up with no $HOME?  Do I need to make a *nix user?  Or perhaps remove migw and create an XP user and use that user to reinstall mingw?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by having a Windows environment variable named HOME.  It was a leftover from somehting unrelated.  Once I deleted it and reinstalled mingw (without deleting the existing one) my home became /home/Administrator.  Pity about the capital A, though.

Answer (score 0):

In msys type cd ..

[image]

Now you're in a not really existent directory `/home` .
If you type cd usr

Now you're in a not really existent directory `/home/usr` .

you will not find `home` or `usr` in your c:\msys\1.0 directory.

MSYS is a collection of GNU utilities such as bash, make, gawk and grep to allow building of applications and programs which depend on traditionally UNIX tools to be present.

An example would be building a library that uses the autotools build system. Users will typically run "./configure" then "make" to build it. The configure shell script requires **a shell script interpreter which is not present on Windows systems**, but provided by MSYS.

**A common misunderstanding is MSYS is "UNIX on Windows"**, MSYS by itself does not contain a compiler or a C library, therefore does not give the ability to magically port UNIX programs over to Windows nor does it provide any UNIX specific functionality like case-sensitive filenames.

Answer (score 0):

My case: I could not find `~/msys/1.0/home/user`  (`user` is my user name)

It is resolved - the following is what I discovered.

`MinGW/MSYS` usually creates a home folder under `C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/user` if you install them as usual (accepting the defaults) and you executes msys.bat successfully. However, it does not create if you happened to have an environment variable called `HOME`. I think it was a left over from my old project.

- First, check your home folder by `$pwd -W`    ($ is a command prompt.)
- Remove `HOME` environment variable.
- Reboot
- Execute `msys.bat` again.
- Now, check where your home folder by `$pwd -W`
- Note: Don't need to reinstall `MinGW/MSYS`.

(a debtor)<><